# Как вставить в существующую таблицу новые строки? (Это в цикле с процедурами)

Tags: sql, sql-server

Добрый вечер всем!

Не понимаю, что не так: не могу обновить таблицу путем вставки в неё новых строк синтаксисом 
    insert into schemaname.Tablename2 
    select * from schemaname.Tablename1

Пояснение:

1. Есть цикл, внутри которого на каждом шаге вызывается процедура
2. Эта процедура считает и создает в базе таблицу (убирает старую, сохраняет на её месте новую).
3. После вызова процедуры на первом шаге цикла я создаю таблицу Tablename2 следующим синтаксисом:

   select *

   into schemaname.Tablename2

   from schemaname.Tablename1

(Tablename2 - по задумке, в неё должны сохраниться результаты всех остальных вызовов процедуры на следующих шагах цикла. В результате должна поучиться огромная таблица с результатами выгрузки со всех шагов)

4. На следующих шагах цикла я хочу вставить в эту же таблицу новые данные - результат вызова процедуры (которая перезаписала таблицу Tablename1).

   insert into schemaname.Tablename2

   select * from schemaname.Tablename1

Но ничего не получается. Ошибка: Tablename2 уже существует в вашей базе.

P.s.: разные способы с insert value с перечислением имен полей, куда надо вставить данные, здесь бессильны, т.к. полей больше 200.

Буду благодарна за любые идеи - как исправить эту ошибку...

Спасибо за внимание!

Код:

```
declare @num_int int

IF OBJECT_ID('Analysis.dbo.TA_FinUsers_AllPeriod') IS NOT NULL DROP TABLE Analysis.dbo.TA_FinUsers_AllPeriod; 

/* determine object of cursor for the loop: it is a "serial number" for each "panel" from the table TA_Dates*/ 

declare db_cursor cursor for 
select num_ from dbo.TA_Dates

/* go to loop */

open db_cursor
/* declare variable, wich will run from step to step in the loop and catch the current value of cursor */


fetch next from db_cursor into @num_int
while  @@FETCH_STATUS = 0
begin 

print @num_int

declare @endd_ datetime
declare @ndays_ int
declare @Year__ int
declare @Month__ int

/* set value for our first variables (next - use it in the  fetching procedure)*/ 

    select @endd_   = End_Datetime from dbo.TA_Dates where num_ = @num_int;
    print  @endd_ 

    select @ndays_  = Days_in_Period from dbo.TA_Dates where num_ = @num_int;
    print @ndays_

    select @Year__  = Year_ from dbo.TA_Dates where num_ = @num_int;  
    print  @Year__

    select @Month__ = Month_  from dbo.TA_Dates where num_ = @num_int; 
    print  @Month__ 


 EXEC Fetch_Execute @endd = @endd_, @ndays = @ndays_, @reg = 0, @par = 0, @par_end = 22, @Year_ = @Year__ , @Month_ = @Month__ ;


 if (@num_int = 1) 
 begin
     select *
     into Analysis.dbo.TA_FinUsers_AllPeriod
     from Analysis.dbo.TA_FinUsers 
 end;

 if (@num_int > 1)
 begin 
    insert into Analysis.dbo.TA_FinUsers_AllPeriod
    select * from Analysis.dbo.TA_FinUsers 
 end;

 fetch next from db_cursor into @num_int
 print @num_int


 end

close db_cursor  
deallocate db_cursor
```

Answer (score 1):

Надо создать таблицу до начала курсора, т.к. иначе Sql Server считает, что вы создаёте таблицу с помощью select into при каждом цикле, несмотря на ваши условия.

Comment: Merci ! Всё работает )

Answer (score 0):

Select INTO создает новую таблицу. Нельзя использовать сущствующую.
Иначе используйте INSERT INTO.

Comment: Я это и сделала в следующем шаге цикла: 

      if (@num_int > 1)
         begin 
            insert into Analysis.dbo.TA_FinUsers_AllPeriod
            select * from Analysis.dbo.TA_FinUsers 
     end;


здесь и выскочила ошибка.